# Removing windows close button in jQuery dialog

Tags: jquery

I want to remove the window close button provided by jQuery.

```
$(function () {
    $('form').submit(function () {

        $("#popUp").dialog({
            modal: true,
            minWidth: 700
        });            
        $('div').close({ onload: function () {
            $('#popUp').remove();
        } 
        });
    });
});
```

This code does not work. How can I remove the close button?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Through **CSS**

```
.ui-dialog-titlebar-close{
    display: none;
}
```

OR **Jquery**

```
$(function () {
    $('form').submit(function () {

        $("#popUp").dialog({
            modal: true,
            minWidth: 700
        }); 
     $("#popUp").dialog("widget").find(".ui-dialog-titlebar-close").hide();           

    });
});
```